# Increase Curve Circle resolution with the amount of instance

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances, fcurves, resolution

I have the following setup here. It use a mesh line, converted in to instance, to create a ring of curve circle. I want the circle resolution of the outer circle to have more resolution than the inner one. For example: The inner-most circle should have 5 sides, the next one is 6 sides, the next one 7 sides,... and so on. How can I create such a setup in Geometry Node? My endgoal is to generate a flower, with increasing amount of flower petal.

[image]

This is the result that I want:

[image]

Please tell me if this is possible in Geometry Node. Thanks!

Comment: If the linked "duplicate" doesn't answer your question, please [Edit] your question explaining how your case differs, cheers!

Comment: Hello, Binh, Markus' suggested link does seem like a very close match, so IMO fair to call this a duplicate. Edit as suggested to re-open, if not.